# Spring Batch - Error/Bug on MultiResourcePartitioner

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

MultiResourcePartitioner is not updating the value of

## {stepExecutionContext['fileName']} if I renamed the file that I have processed before.

Initially, I processed "FILE1.TXT" and for some reasons the processing fails then I renamed the file to "FILE2.TXT" Spring batch still looking for "FILE1.TXT". So my work around is to delete all records on BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT in order to pickup the new file.

I am not sure if this a bug or maybe I missing some configurations but I am expecting that the spring batch will always pickup the files in the directory and not in the DB.

Comment: you can use https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH/ to post the bug, afaik it is normal behaviour, spring batch cant see your changes on the outside (file system), you could hack the executionContext (by hand, by listener)

Comment: Thanks Michael. I've created a bug.

Answer (score 0):

When you start the partitioned step, all of the `ExecutionContext`s are created, one for each file.  Upon a restart, the goal for a partitioned job is to finish the work that was already partitioned...aka the partitioner isn't going to run again.  This is the designed behavior.

Comment: My scenario is common in production in which the bad file needs to rectify and rename it via timestamp. As I mentioned, I have work around (deleting all records from BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT) but to me this a hack. I wish spring batch will enhance the partitioned step behavior in order to handle the said scenario.

Comment: I think (I haven't tried this) you could set the step to be rerun on a restart...That may rerun the partitioner (the fundamental issue for you).  However, what you're asking for is that a restart behave differently than the initial run which isn't correct.  A restart, by design, should restart the work that was defined before.  You could create your own partitioner that did some other method of defining what a Partition is so that the new file would be picked up...but that's related directly to your use case.

Comment: Assuming I don't need the restart functionality. would it be nice if Spring batch has a Boolean property configuration that will optionally pickup the files in the directory instead?

Comment: That isn't a function of the partitioner...it's how a partitioned step works.  Have you tried to configure the step to be rerun (instead of being restarted) via setting `allow-start-if-complete=true`?

Comment: I have tried the rerun option and I have no problem with the single threaded job even i renamed the files.

Comment: I tried this allow-start-if-complete=true but it is no luck.